# Node.js send message to GCM server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to GCM server to forward to another phone.  The request keeps saying 400.  I've checked the code close to a hundred times, but I'll put it up just in case.  I also have changed the registration token parameter to registration_id and various others, along with changing the data to arrays etc.  Just to be clear that the API key and Registration ID work, I can get a push notification from this Web site:

http://demo.androidhive.info/gcm_chat/push_test.php

Here's the code:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var gcmSender = new gcm.Sender('A......1234568AAA'); //my api key

var GCMmessage = new gcm.Message();
GCMmessage.addData("message", message);
GCMmessage.addData("from", from);

GCMmessage.addNotification('title', 'Alert!!!');
GCMmessage.addNotification('body', 'Abnormal data access');
GCMmessage.addNotification('icon', 'ic_launcher');

var regtoken = response.GCM.RegID; //data returned from another function
                                   //Gives the RegID for a specific user      

gcmSender.send(GCMmessage, {"to" : regtoken}, function(err, gcmResponse) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(gcmResponse);
        console.log("message sent");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that it is best to send your gcm message directly using an npm module like 'request' or something similar.  When I sent a message using that I received a very detailed error message telling me that 'from' is a reserved word.  I'm not sure if that was the whole issue, but having a detailed error message made the code modification pretty easy.